# Formatting output of multithreading output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def run_test_function(x, fun_arg2, fun_arg3, fun_arg4):
    # this is an example
    for a in fun_arg2:
        for b in fun_arg3:
            print(x)
            print(a)
            print(b)
            print(fun_arg4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = 1,2,3,4
    arg2 = "hello"
    arg3 = "world"
    arg4 = "!"

    process_func = partial(run_test_function, fun_arg2=arg2, fun_arg3=arg3, fun_arg4=arg4)

    my_pool = Pool(8)
    my_pool.map(process_func, arg1)
```

For this code, I am getting output as below:

```
~/test $ python2.7 so10.py
1 
  hello 
     world 
         !
2 
  hello 
     world 
          !
3 
   hello 
      world 
           !
4 
     hello 
         world 
              !
```

Problem with this code is, when this output has lengthy string, at that time, output is not understandable. As of now I am expecting output be like :

```
1 
hello 
world 
!
2 
hello 
world 
!
3 
hello 
world 
!
4 
hello 
world 
!
```

Moreover after getting the output, my CLI is getting hung, can you please give some inputs on that?

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes when CR/LF interpretation is broken.
You can always put a line in end of your code :

```
import os
os.system('stty sane')
```